# boost::asio udp - How do I get many mutable buffers filled?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to receive many udp messages from one async_receive call.  My messages are approx. 60 bytes long.

I'm giving an `async_receive` call a buffer array very similar to the boost docs but can't seem to get all the buffers filled.

```
char d1[128];
char d2[128];
char d3[128];

boost::array<boost::asio::mutable_buffer, 3> bufs = 
{
   boost::asio::buffer(d1),
   boost::asio::buffer(d2),
   boost::asio::buffer(d3) 
};

_socket.async_receive(bufs, handler);
```

When my handler gets called the `bytes_transferred` is equal to one message length (i.e. 60).

Any thoughts on how I can get the second and third buffer populated?  Also, how do I now if the second and third mutable buffer were populated?

Comment: post some code that we can compile, your pseudo code does not describe the problem accurately enough.

Comment: If you need more than one buffer filled, you have to do multiple calls to async_receive(). Each call to async_receive() receives one UDP datagram (and no, you shall not put two calls to async_receive() in a row). Another story would be, e.g. to receive the header and body of a message in to two buffers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive multiple datagrams in a single call, you generally (regardless of Boost) need to use [recvmmsg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html).  From what I can tell, Boost does not use recvmmsg, so you would need to use it yourself with the native socket held by Boost ASIO.  The advantage of doing this is that you can reduce system calls when multiple datagrams are available.